# input entered by user must return all the index in the list with that input in its name

Tags: python, list

For example, if I enter: `"the"`

I need to be able detect all of the titles in my list that has `"the"` in it.

```
my_list = ["The offspring", "legends", "the legends", "soraka"]
```

Given the list above, it should return `"The offspring"` and `"the legends"`.
I am able to detect titles if I write the whole name, but I am having trouble when I am asked to enter a part of the title, e.g. `"the"`, and I am not sure what kind of function or loop to use at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['the offspring','legends','the legends','soraka']

for i in lst:
    if 'the' in i:
        print(i)
```

This is how I would check inside of the list, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner will handle it for you.

```
filter(lambda x: "the" in x.lower().split(), ["The foo", "bar The", "baz"])
```

The reason to split is to match whole words only.